# Xcode - TableView -> delete row - localNotification

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, localnotification, cocoa-touch

My problem is that my delete method do not delete the right row!

In this tableView the user can save localNotifications for a special date. So if I create more than one localNot, the delete method does not delete the selected row! It deletes the last entry only ...

- 26.02.2012 delete third
- 27.02.2012 delete second
- etc...     delete first

Whats wrong?

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(tableView.editing && editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notification];
        [notificationsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"%@", notification);
        // Animate the deletion from the table.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }

}


-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable. 
    // UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this line does: ` [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:notifcation];` but you don't appear to have changed the value of "notifcation" anywhere.  I'm assuming you set it when the last one was added, and then forgot to reset it to the value of the new notifcation.  Also, does the animation get rid of the right row before the tableView reloads the data?

Comment: Hi, so whazt should I do now? I understand your info, but I dont now what do to really... How can I update the value?????

Comment: Comment out [tableView reloadData]; and see if it deletes the right row.  If it does, something is wrong with the array; if it doesn't, something is wrong with your 'deleteRowsAtIndexPaths'.